# From object to Json to Xml to object

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have these classes:

```
public class House
{
    public MyObject[] Objects { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

that I instantiate like this:

```
var house1 = new House
{
     Objects = new MyObject[]
     {
          new MyObject() { Name = "Name1" },
          new MyObject() { Name = "Name2" }
     }
 };
```

Then I get its json representation:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(house1, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

From the latter I get the relative XML:

```
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "House", true);
string xmlString = doc.OuterXml;
```

And finally I transform the xml into the object of the initial type:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(House));
TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
House house2 = (House)serializer.Deserialize(reader)
```

The questions are:

- Why house1 is different from house2? (house2.Objects is empty!)
- What am I doing wrong?

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1nk2fB) you can find a dotnetfiddle example

Comment: Probably because of the JSON namespace on your XML elements. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Generated XML by JSON serializer:

```xml
<House xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json" json:type="Program+House, ayusorzt">
    <Objects json:type="Program+MyObject, ayusorzt">
       <Name>
           Name1
       </Name>
    </Objects> 
    <Objects json:type="Program+MyObject, ayusorzt">
       <Name>
           Name2
       </Name>
    </Objects>
</House>
```

`XMLSerializer` can't deserailze this XML object. Right XML object should look like this:

```xml
<House>
    <Objects>
       <MyObject>
           <Name>
               Name1
           </Name>
       </MyObject>       
       <MyObject>
           <Name>
               Name2
           </Name>
       </MyObject>
    </Objects> 
</House>
```

You can fix it by following code:

```cs
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer<House>();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<House>();

using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
    string yourXml = textWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: _"Right XML object should look like this"_ - well both are correct XML, the former being somewhat more correct.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In your opinion is it possible to add the xsi:type attribute for objects of type MyObject? If yes how could I do?

Answer (score 0):

The XML generated by the `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode` method is not interoperable with the `XmlSerializer`.

In order to deserialize the XML, you need to use Newtonsoft.Json itself

```cs
string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
House house2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<House>(json2);
```

### EDIT

For generating XML from json that works with the `XmlSerializer`, deserialize the JSON to an object and then use the `XmlSerializer` to generate the XML.

```cs
const string json = "{\"Objects\":[{\"Name\":\"Name1\"},{\"Name\":\"Name2\"}]}";
        
House house = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<House>(json);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(House));
        
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, house);
}

//Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer; my starting point is the Json string and in your example code you suppose to already have a XML "doc" string. From starting Json to the final XML what conversion steps should I perform?

Comment: @DanieleMereu, I should've specified better. My response addresses the problem you're facing in your code where on deserializing the XML generated by `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode` using `XmlSerializer`. You can't take the XML output from `Newtonsoft.Json` and manipulate it with  `XmlSerializer`. If you looking to convert JSON to XML that is compatible with `XmlSerializer`, then deserialize the JSON to an object and generate the XML using an `XmlSerializer`

Comment: thank you now I understand. One more thing, in your opinion, is it possible during serialization to include the xsi:type attribute for objects? (for example: <MyObject xsi:type="MyObject">)

Comment: the negative side of your solution is that I need to instantiate the House object to perform the consequent conversion to XML. Can't do it without?

Comment: @DanieleMereu, I don't know of a robust, generic way to get from JSON to XML directly.